# Source() from server.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a R file containing some variables I use in my general app.
I was minding if it was possible to source this R file from my server.R and then output it into the ui.R
Do you know if it is possible or do you know some advices ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with these variables. If you just want to declare some global variables or functions, the easiest way would be to put them in a file named `global.R` as Shiny will source it by itself automatically (as long as it is in the same folder as your app).

Comment: Why to hardcode parameters in `server.R`? Store them in a separate `yaml` file that could be loaded by `server.R` or `ui.R`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have my ui.R where I need to source my file.R . My problem is that I can't source directly from the ui besause the name of "file.R" might change. Thereby I need to write something like this : source(file = variable, local = TRUE)